# Order By case when then with multiple ASC/DESC

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case, case-when

Hope this question has not been ask already.
My problem is :

Do you know how to do something like that

```
  ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN job = "jounalist" then 1, date desc 
    WHEN job = "teacher" then 2, class asc
    WHEN job = "dev" then 3, code asc 
    ELSE 4
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate `case` expressions.  I'm not sure what `1`, `2`, and `3` represent.  Let me assume they are meant to put the results in the order of the `CASE` expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN job = 'journalist' THEN 1
               WHEN job = 'teacher' THEN 2
               WHEN job = 'dev' THEN 3
               ELSE 4
          END),
         (CASE WHEN job = 'journalist' THEN date END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN job = 'teacher' THEN class END),
         (CASE WHEN job = 'code' THEN code END)
```

A `CASE` expression returns a single type.  For this purpose, I don't recommend converting values to a single type.  Instead, just use separate keys in the `ORDER BY` for the different groups.

I should also point out that some databases might have special functionality that would simplify some of this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN job = "jounalist" then 1 
    WHEN job = "teacher" then 2
    WHEN job = "dev" then 3 
    ELSE 4
  END asc
  CASE 
    WHEN job = "jounalist" then Right(cast(1000000000 + Datediff(second, date, GetDate()) as nvarchar(100)),  9) 
    WHEN job = "teacher" then class
    WHEN job = "dev" then code
    ELSE N''
  END asc
```

You can only return a single column of one data type from a case expression. I assume that `class` and `code` are `nvarchar` columns, and hence convert the time difference from date to now to an `nvarchar(100)`. Also, assuming the value of column `date` is before the current date/time, and less than 1000000000 seconds so, the expression on it delives a 0-padded string which nicely sorts ascending the same way that sorting backwards on the date would sort.